# How can I render a red box?

Tags: javascript, button, rendering

I want to render a red box on my screen, clicking on the button "Criar quadrado". My code can do it, but just once. I want to render a red box on each click. That's my code :

```js
//Crie um botão que ao ser clicado cria um novo elemento em tela com a forma de um quadrado
//vermelho com 100px de altura e largura. Sempre que o botão for clicado um novo quadrado deve
//aparecer na tela.

function criarQuadrado() {
  var boxElement = document.querySelector(".box");

  boxElement.style.width = 300;
  boxElement.style.height = 300;
  boxElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button onclick="criarQuadrado()">Criar quadrado</button>
```

It renders, but I want on each click another box side by side. How can I do it?

Comment: First, you need to add the box somewhere to the DOM for it to show up. And second, you need to call the function otherwise the code won't be executed.

Answer (score 3):

```js
      function criarQuadrado() {
        var boxElement = document.createElement("div")
    
        boxElement.style.width = "30px";
        boxElement.style.height = "30px";
        boxElement.style.display = "inline-block";
        boxElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
        
        var container = document.getElementById("container")
        container.appendChild(boxElement)
      }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="criarQuadrado()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to create a new element every time the button is clicked using `document.createElement()`, then you can append it to something such as a div

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', criarQuadrado)


function criarQuadrado() {
  var boxElement = document.createElement('div')

  boxElement.style.width = '20px';
  boxElement.style.height = '20px';
  boxElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
  boxElement.style.float = 'left';

  document.querySelector('.boxes').appendChild(boxElement)
}
```

```css
.boxes{margin-top: 20px}
```

```html
<button>Add Box</button>
<div class="boxes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mostraBox(){

var boxElement = document.querySelector('.box');
var color =  "#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);

boxElement.style.width = 100;
boxElement.style.height = 100;
boxElement.style.backgroundColor = color;

return color;
}
```

Comment: NO HMTL FAÇA ASSIM
<div id="app">
        <button onclick="mostraBox()">Me Pressione</button>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: You should generally avoid answers with only code. While the code may work it is still a good practice to add a few words explaining how you have arrived at your answer.